# FromSqlRaw and FromSqlInterpolated return empty set if I use param overload

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core

I have a stored procedure named "SearchContacts" defined in a `MySQL 8.x` database, which has only one parameter:

```
SearchContacts(searchQuery VARCHAR(255))
```

Inside my `ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC` project, to call this SP I have a `DbContext`, which contains this field and its related `OnModelCreating` configuration:

```
protected DbSet<SearchContacts> SearchContactsSP { get; set; }

...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<SearchContacts>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(k => k.IdContact);
    }

    ...
}
```

---

**PREMISE:** Database is not empty.

If I run this code:

```
string search = "claire";

var result = SearchContactsSP.FromSqlRaw(
    sql: $"CALL `SearchContacts`('{search}')"
)
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
.AsNoTracking();
```

everything works fine and I have a **non-empty** set returned.

Since I'm aware that this could be a serious SQL Injection vulnerability, I started replacing code above with this logic:

```
var result = SearchContactsSP.FromSqlRaw(
    sql: "CALL `SearchContacts`('{0}')",
    search
)
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
.AsNoTracking();
```

but it returns empty set. Same happens with this:

```
var result = SearchContactsSP.FromSqlInterpolated(
    sql: $"CALL `SearchContacts`('{search}')"
)
.IgnoreQueryFilters()
.AsNoTracking();
```

why this happens?

---

Any other solution to run the SP better are welcome, since I'm not really satisfacted with the way I found to call it.

---

Provider: `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Json.Microsoft (3.2.4)`

Comment: Did you enable debug logging to see the actual SQL queries produced?

Comment: @JakubFojtik Can you be more specific with "debug logging"?

Comment: You need to remove ' ' around value you pass, because it's treated as literal string then (by sql). In working case it IS literal string you pass, but in other cases you use parameters.

Comment: @Evk removing quotes does not work.

Comment: You are removing them around value, not procedure name? It should be `SearchContacts`({search}) in last (sql interpolated) case

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a debugging info rather than an answer, because from what you wrote it should work perfectly:

In your appsettings.json you should change this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

This will let you see the generated SQL in the Output window so you can check it.

Also you should try changing the EFCore provider, e.g. to the normal one: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore to rule out provider bugs.

If nothing helps then make a simple example app to find out the problem, otherwise it can be hidden in any piece of code you have. Double check that what you wrote is right and that you didn't leave out important info, like the exact datatype of the column.

**EDIT**

Could you try an ADO.NET approach?:

```
SearchContactsSP.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SearchContacts (@p0)", parameters: new[] { search });
```

Maybe EF is confused that you start the query from a supposedly table context...

BTW please incorporate @Evk's suggestion to remove quotes around the parameter value - once it is a parameter it does not need quotes, it is removed from the SQL structure. Quotes would just wrap it's value again.

Idea source: [tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` does not provide Json fields support at the moment, which I need at most. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @ewhoambra Okay but you could still check if the interpolated call works with the Mysql provider. I think there must be a bug in the json provider because supporting just 1 method out of 3 seems strange. Did you try the debug log to see the generated SQL in VS Output window?

Comment: your suggestion to turn on Debug logging was good, but wasn't enough (unfortunately), since log only shows: ```CALL `SearchContacts`('@p0')``` suggesting no replacing with parameters, but it was only misleading, because when I tried to send a wrong query on purpose, MySQL returned me a query error with fully replaced query. I found out that if searchQuery was null (due to my mistake) it would print 'null' causing no match in the set.

Comment: You are right, i forgot that parameters are not fully expanded in the log, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Turning on debug logging as other answer and comments suggested was a good advice, but also misleading, because (on query execution) log would print this:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Debug: Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[p0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CALL `SearchContacts`(@p0)
```

This log mislead me into thinking that there were no replacing by the `FromSqlRaw()` method; i tried to send a wrong query, to cause MySQL query error and I saw a fully replaced query.

In my case, since my parameter `searchQuery` could also be null (in case of full contacts listing), I put this wrong conditional expression into the `FromSqlRaw` calling:

```
(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchQuery) ? $"'{searchQuery}'" : "NULL")
```

that would cause an execution like this:

```
CALL `SearchContacts`('NULL')
```

I solved the issue by just changing the conditional expression into this:

```
[...] ? $"{searchQuery}'" : null)
```

Comment: So the solution was to remove quotes like @evk said? Does it work now?

Comment: Not properly, it was a "quotes issue", but it was not about SP name, but that `"NULL"` with quotes caused issues.